# How to do a cartesian join of a numpy array and a pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, cartesian-product

I have a numpy array `ids` (unique) and a pandas series `dates`.

I want to create a pandas dataframe that is a cartesian product of `ids` and `dates` with columns `id` and `date` grouped by date.

e.g., `ids = [1, 2]` and `dates = [10032023, 10042023]`, with resulting dataframe:

```
id     date
1      10032023
2      10032023
1      10042023
2      10042023
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do this using the existing vectorized operations in pandas. My currently approach is just to iterate over both and assign the rows individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `product` method from the built-in `itertools` module to achieve this.

The cartesian product is done like this:

```py
from itertools import product

array1 = [1, 2, 3]
array2 = ['a', 'b']

result = list(product(array1, array2))
print(result)
```

which results in this:

```
[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b')]
```

The docs are here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

The docs point out that this is not vectorised, but in fact this:

> Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example, `product(A, B)` returns the same as `((x,y) for x in A for y in B)`.

Answer (score 1):

[pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) should work in this case, we should just specify `how=cross` to do cross product. We also need to convert the initial ndarray to a Series and ensure both are named. If any series is unnamed we could just handle this with `series.name = "hoopla"`.

Here's a demo, assuming you already have a series and numpy array created, we would only need the last 2 lines:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,2])

df2 = pd.Series([10032023, 10042023], name="df2")

df1 = pd.Series(arr, name="df1")
cross_prod = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="cross")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: `MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False`

Comment: How are you creating your dataframes? Seems like its complaining that there are no columns that share the same name in your dataframes. If you have more than one column in either dataframe, you'll have to specify which column you want to merge on using `pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on="df1 column name", right_on="df2 column name", how="cross")`. Check out [these docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Comment: I actually just copy and pasted your code in your answer

Comment: Just updated the code to use `pd.Series` instead of `df.Series`. Other than fixing the error in my code, are you using pandas `2.1.4` as well?

Answer (score 1):

use `MultiIndex.from_product`

```
ids = [1, 2]
dates = [10032023, 10042023]
out = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, ids]).to_frame(index=False)\
        .reindex([1, 0], axis=1).set_axis(['id', 'date'], axis=1)
```

out

```
    id  date
0   1   10032023
1   2   10032023
2   1   10042023
3   2   10042023
```